# Having changing text-boxes/drop-downs appear when certain item is picked from a drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dom-events

Currently in my code I have one drop-down menu. This drop-down menu has three options the user can pick from. Complete needs to have a text-box appear if it is selected. Abandon needs to have a drop-down menu to show up. Then Transfer works the same way. A drop-down menu needs to appear for it as well.

My HTML code for the first drop-down:

```
<select name="Action" id="ActionDD" required onchange="showHide()">
    <option value="">Action:</option>
    <option value="complete">Complete</option>
    <option value="abandon">Abandon</option>
    <option value="transfer">Transfer</option>
</select>
```

My HTML code for the Text-box that needs to appear with Complete picked from first drop-down menu

```
<input type="text" name="RemNUM" id="REMtextBox" placeholder="Remedy Number" maxlength="10" style="display:none;"/>
```

My HTML code for the drop-down that needs to appear with abandon picked from first drop-down menu

```
    <select name="Reason" id="ReasonDD" style="display:none;" required>
    <option value="">Reason:</option>
    <option value="NoShow">No Show</option>
    <option value="Unfixable">Unfixable</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Then lastly my JavaScript code I have that is doing some of these tasks. But when I select something else from the first drop-down menu after something has already been picked it will show both the new text-box or the new drop-down menu together. I need help getting both of them to show up by themselves and clear the old selected action.

```
    function showHide()
 {

  var val = document.getElementById("ActionDD").value;

  if(val == "complete")
   document.getElementById("REMtextBox").style.display = 'inline-block';
  else if(val == "abondon")
   document.getElementById("ReasonDD").style.display = 'inline-block';
  else if(val == "C")
   document.getElementById("ThirdTextBoxId").style.display = 'inline-block';
  else if(val == "D")
   document.getElementById("FourthTextBoxId").style.display = 'inline-block';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give all your hidden elements class and in showHide function first hide all elements and then show the one you want.

so your js code will be

```
showHide = function()
{
    var showHideItems = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden-items');
    for(var i =0;i<showHideItems.length;i++){
        showHideItems[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var val = document.getElementById("ActionDD").value;

    if(val == "complete")
     document.getElementById("REMtextBox").style.display = 'inline-block';
    else if(val == "abandon")
     document.getElementById("ReasonDD").style.display = 'inline-block';
    else if(val == "C")
     document.getElementById("ThirdTextBoxId").style.display = 'inline-block';
    else if(val == "D")
     document.getElementById("FourthTextBoxId").style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

and your html will be

```
<select name="Action" id="ActionDD" required onchange="showHide()">
    <option value="">Action:</option>
    <option value="complete">Complete</option>
    <option value="abandon">Abandon</option>
    <option value="transfer">Transfer</option>
</select>

<input class="hidden-items" type="text" name="RemNUM" id="REMtextBox" placeholder="Remedy Number" maxlength="10" style="display:none;"/>
<select class="hidden-items" name="Reason" id="ReasonDD" style="display:none;" required>
    <option value="">Reason:</option>
    <option value="NoShow">No Show</option>
    <option value="Unfixable">Unfixable</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

here is working jsfiddle for you code https://jsfiddle.net/jpj42ojz/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

You can add a empty `div` with an ID below your selection and change the `innerHTML` of that `div` with your HTML you want to show based on the selection the user makes.

I edited your existing code so you can see what I mean:

```js
function showHide() {
  var val = document.getElementById("ActionDD").value;
  var remTextBox = document.getElementById("REMtextBox");
  var reasonDD = document.getElementById("ReasonDD");
  var thirdTextBoxId = document.getElementById("ThirdTextBoxId");
  var fourthTextBox = document.getElementById("FourthTextBoxId");
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  
  var remTextBoxHTML = '<input type="text" name="RemNUM" id="REMtextBox" placeholder="Remedy Number" maxlength="10"/>';
  
  var reasonDDHTML = '<select name="Reason" required><option value="">Reason:</option><option value="NoShow">No Show</option><option value="Unfixable">Unfixable</option><option value="other">Other</option></select>';
  
  if(val == "complete") {
    result.innerHTML = remTextBoxHTML;
  } else if(val == "abandon") {
    result.innerHTML = reasonDDHTML;
  } else if(val == "C") {
    result.innerHTML = '';
  } else if(val == "D") {
    result.innerHTML = '';
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="Action" id="ActionDD" required onchange="showHide()">
    <option value="">Action:</option>
    <option value="complete">Complete</option>
    <option value="abandon">Abandon</option>
    <option value="transfer">Transfer</option>
</select>

<div id="result">

</div>
```